# Optimizing slow SELECT query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have issue with optimizing this query which takes 13s

```
SELECT `user_id`,`op`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `imported_customer` 
WHERE (`id` IN (
      SELECT `imported_customer_id` FROM `history`
      WHERE `date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
      GROUP BY `imported_customer_id` 
      HAVING MAX(`event_type_id`)= 2
      )
) 
GROUP BY `op` 
ORDER BY `user_id`, `op`
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type      table       type   possible_keys    key              key_len  ref rows Extra
1   PRIMARY imported_customer   index                    op                 35      1718    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  history index                 imported_customer_id  8       2       Using where
```

The subquery is fine, it runs in 38ms, and resulting list for in operator is arround 300 numbers, which should be fine.

So the only thing which rests is the count(*), with GROUP and ORDER in primary query.

Explain for that query tells "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort", which is sign of wrong optimized query.

On table imported_customer are indexes for id, user_id and op.

But the query is still slow, how to optimize it?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02d37/2/0 -(columns not used in query not included) due to small amount of data it's fast but explain looks same

Comment: can you post your create table statement and some example data en post it on sqlfiddle and post the link here?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added sql fiddle

Comment: How big are your tables? How many rows in each?

Comment: currently in prod: imported_customer around 2000 rows, history around 6000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try replacing your `WHERE ... IN ()` with a `JOIN` like so (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bb51/1/0):

```
   SELECT user_id,op, COUNT(*) AS count
     FROM imported_customer i 
     JOIN (
             SELECT imported_customer_id 
               FROM history
               WHERE `date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
            GROUP BY imported_customer_id 
              HAVING MAX(event_type_id)= 2
          ) h ON i.id = h.imported_customer_id
 GROUP BY user_id, op 
 ORDER BY user_id, op
```

You should consider using a covering index `(date, imported_customer_id, event_type_id)`  on your history table to assist in the generation of the aggregate filtered by date.

You should consider using a compound index `(id, user_id, op)` on your imported customer table for the same reason.

Notice that the index selection in SQL Fiddle is not likely to be the same as it will be on a scaled up query.

Notice also that you were using, and maybe misusing, the pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`.

Don't be baffled by "Using temporary; using filesort."  The sort of aggregate computation you are doing in your outer query requires those operations.  Filesort doesn't always mean a real file; it can mean the sorting of an in-memory intermediate result.  You are correct that "using where" isn't a sign of good optimization.

Comment: Thanks, query time has dropped from 13s to only 10ms

Comment: Hooray! It's usually harder than that to optimize queries.

Comment: `INDEX(date)` might help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try adding an index like this on your table imported_customer:

```
INDEX `test2` (`user_id`,`op`)
```

and then use

```
group by (`user_id`,`op`)
```

Comment: using 'group by (`user_id`,`op`)'  gives me error 'Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)' and only adding index didn't speed up query

Comment: @Rfilip it should be GROUP BY `user_id`,`op` without the ( and )

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, copy-paste from index and missing to delete  brackets !

Comment: @RaymondNijland Query time after editing GROUP BY is same ,alhough  explain is better "Using where;Using index"